# Python loop code won't print with solver code, possible other problem?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple solver that fills in the 0's of the 3x3 grid. The numbers are from 1-9. Based on the advice advise I got from one user I tried to make the loop work but it still does not work?

```
import numpy as np

grid = [[0, 2, 3],
        [4, 0, 5],
        [6, 7, 0]]

def possible(number, grid):
    for x in grid:
        if number in x:
            return False
        else:
            return True

def solve():    
    global grid
    for number in grid:
        for m in number:            
            if m == 0:
                for number in range(1,10):
                    if possible(number, grid):
                        grid = number                        
                        solve()
                return
    print(np.matrix(grid))

solve()
```

Comment: You used ```n``` in two loops which are nested. You should use another variable than ```n``` in one of them. Generally it is better to use meaningful names for variables!

Comment: What is the goal of your script? What are you trying to achieve? Furthermore, you are using solve() in the the def solve() and you using 'n' in the first and in the nested for-loop.

Comment: I'm trying to create a simple solver that fills in the 0's of the 3x3 grid. The numbers are from 1-9. Its like a very simplified version of sudoku with 1 box instead of 9